# debugging rubymotion wrapped web view

Tags: ios, css, iphone, rubymotion

I'm trying to debug the webview wrapped by a "native" iOS rubymotion app, but I'm not sure what tools exist to do this. Specifically, I'm trying to debug the CSS and HTML of the application. Is there a way to do this using rubymotion or some other toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it for Android : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews

I would look for similar on iOS, or perhaps you can use Android for development then convert to iOS.